# How to make a text change foreground color after onDelete of a list item in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

Let's say I have the following list:

```
List {
    ForEach(users, id: \.self) { user in
        Text(user)
    }
    .onDelete(perform: delete)
}
```

If I have a text that is outside of the list, is there a way I can add some kind of event or make .onDelete a function where once the list item is deleted, the text that is outside of the list changes to a red color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible approach (scratchy)

```
@State private var userDeleted = false

var body: some View {
    ...
    Text("TEST")
       .foregroundColor(self.userDeleted ? .red : .primary)
    ...
}

func delete(from source: IndexSet?) {
    users.remove(atOffsets: source!)
    self.userDeleted = true
}
```

Comment: I see this as being one way, but is it required that you have to depend on state variables? There is no way to have a listener or 'function' within remove() or 'watch' for delete events that you can use to affect the foreground color?